# How to validate csrf token at server side(nodeJs) sent via ajax call

Tags: node.js, csrf, csrf-protection

In my nodeJs application i'm using quite a few Ajax calls and want to guard those call against the CSRF attacks.

I am using [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) for this and it works perfectly fine as long as the request is normal request. In this case all we need to do is just pass the token from route to view and embed it to your form.When form is submitted with the token csrf takes care of it. if it doesn't match then invalid csrf token error is shown.

But when it comes to Ajax call can't figure out how to do this to guard those ajax calls,this is what i have got to know after googling for few hours.Since we need a token for Ajax call,can add to a meta tag or something to the main page.Upon each Ajax call we have to find the csrf token and either add it to the request header or body i,e payload.

Use a middleware to save the token in your response.

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfToken = csrf();

......some code here

app.use(csrfToken);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {      
   res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});
```

We need to add it to layout or something so that we can grab it for each Ajax call.

```
<head>
  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <meta name="_csrf" content="{{_csrf}}"/>
  ....
</head>
```

For setting up the token in Ajax call i did something like this.

```
var csrf_header = 'X-CSRF-Token';

var setToken = function (securityToken) {
  jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, _, xhr) {
    if (!xhr.crossDomain) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(csrf_header, securityToken);
    }
  });
};
```

Is it wise to add token to request header or go ahead with adding it to request body ?

Upto this point i am good but how can we validate the token we are gonna sent on server.

Any help or any pointer will be much appreciated!!